# CherryPy REST Authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, cherrypy

I am quite new to Python and CherryPy and trying to build a basic web application which will query data from the server with a RESTful API. I am trying to do it the right way from the start. One part I have not been able to figure out is authentication for the API as REST is supposed to be stateless, and you don't use sessions.

I want to be able to use my API with "native clients" which does not have Cookies, so using session Cookies is not an option. The data will be accessed with AJAX in an HTML. OAuth seems like an option but I dont want to rely on a third party to provide the login service (Facebook was offline for almost a day a few weeks ago)

Can anyone point me in the right direction, which would work with CherryPy?

Comment: OAuth seems like an option for what? Once you do the authorization you still have to keep the session somehow like in a cookie or by changing the state of the connection. Basically what you're saying is "i want the server to know that I'm authorized without knowing this". I suggest changing your assumptions and make those "native clients" support cookies (or equivalent). Otherwise I doubt there is much you can do.

Comment: @freakish Cookies should not be used with REST, they then become stateful. REST is supposed authenticate by tokens without having to store any state or session data on the server. Have a look at [http://restcookbook.com/Basics/loggingin/](http://restcookbook.com/Basics/loggingin/).

Comment: Dude, there is no conceptual difference between a cookie and a token. It's just a word. Besides where would you store that token on the client side? If you say that the client does not support cookies. And the connection does not become stateful with cookies.

Comment: There is a distinction between the client / user agent being stateless, and and the API / server being stateless.  The REST requirement only pertains to the server.  The basic premise is that Either the server remembers who is logged in (between requests), which is statefull on the server, or else the client must send something (cookie/HTTP-auth/token/signature) to authenticate itself on every request, in which case the server needs to check that on every request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "the right way" for RESTful authentication. REST is not an API silver bullet per se. There are you requirements to it, and solutions with their pros and cons that you need to weigh. However, I'll tell about HTTP standard methods that will work on CherryPy out-of-the-box.

The article you linked in your comment is pretty clear about the simple way to do authentication in stateless fashion -- [Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on HTTPS. There's also [Digest Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication), which the doesn't transfer password as such and prevents replay attacks, so it's fine to use it on plain HTTP.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


userpassdict  = {'user1': 'passwd'}
checkpassword = cherrypy.lib.auth_basic.checkpassword_dict(userpassdict)
get_ha1       = cherrypy.lib.auth_digest.get_ha1_dict_plain(userpassdict)

config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  },
  '/' : {
    # HTTP verb dispatcher
    'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
    # JSON response
    'tools.json_out.on' : True,
    # Basic Auth
    'tools.auth_basic.on'            : True,
    'tools.auth_basic.realm'         : 'Walled garden',
    'tools.auth_basic.checkpassword' : checkpassword,
    # Digest Auth
    #'tools.auth_digest.on'      : True,
    #'tools.auth_digest.realm'   : 'Walled garden',
    #'tools.auth_digest.get_ha1' : get_ha1,
    #'tools.auth_digest.key'     : 'put random secret here',
  }
}


class Document:
  '''Test like:
  curl --user user1:passwd --request GET http://localhost:8080/api/document
  curl --user user1:passwd --request GET http://localhost:8080/api/document/2
  curl --user user1:passwd --request POST --data name="new entry" http://localhost:8080/api/document
  curl --user user1:passwd --request PUT --data name="new entry2" http://localhost:8080/api/document/4
  curl --user user1:passwd --request DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/document/4
  '''

  _store  = None
  exposed = True


  def __init__(self):
    self._store = {
      1 : {'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'},
      2 : {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'},
      3 : {'id': 3, 'name': 'baz'},
      4 : {'id': 4, 'name': 'qux'},
    }

  def GET(self, id = None):
    if id:
      return self._store[int(id)]
    else:
      return self._store.values()

  def POST(self, **kwargs):
    id = max(self._store.keys()) + 1
    self._store[id] = {'id': id, 'name': kwargs['name']}
    return id    

  def PUT(self, id, **kwargs):
    self._store[int(id)].update(kwargs)

  def DELETE(self, id):
    self._store.pop(int(id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(Document(), '/api/document', config)
```