# CherryPy authentication token

Tags: authentication, token, cherrypy

This is my first question in SO, sorry if it's poorly structured.
I'm a relative noob developer trying to make a REST Api with Token Authentication. I already made one with Flask and I want to make the same one with the help of CherryPy. The problem is that I'm quite lost finding some sort of plugin for CherryPy, I'm either blind or I just can't find examples nor plugins in order to make the token authentication. Could someone help me? Any info or advice will be of great help :)

This is what I achieved with Flask https://github.com/themese/flask-api

Really my problem is that with Flask and Cherrypy i found the same issue with the token auth, but with various SO posts and wiki info, I managed to code the token auth. I just seem not to be able to reporduce it with Cherrypy, perhaps the lack of info :(

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please the code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: CherryPy isn't all-in-one box like Django. It's a microframework and it's really minimalistic. It only provides some fundamental tools needed for an HTTP web-server, so you can use them to build your apps. Look at so-called [`cherrypy tools`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#per-request-functions) to get some idea of identifying whom the token belongs to and putting it into the `cherrypy.request` context

Comment: Perhaps with cherrypy tools I can manually manage the token, do you know if there is any plugin/tool that already manages it, I don't seem able to find any.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this post is a little old, but I would recommend you look at implementing tokens with JWT.  You should use the [PyJWT](http://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package and create a [CherryPy Tool](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#tools) for route authentication & authorization checks.

Another method would be to generate a token using something like a uuid4 hex and persisting that token in your db.

I'd recommend you investigate JWT and how to implement it properly -  Auth0.com.

Comment: Probably this is a better answer, just it came a bit more than a year ago. I still appreciate the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob too. probably more so. Just trying to help.

From the docs:
Authentication
CherryPy provides support for two very simple authentication mechanisms, both described in RFC 2617: Basic and Digest. They are most commonly known to trigger a browser’s popup asking users their name and password.

link: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html#authentication

Comment: Yes I know, but a basic or digest auth is a bit odd and ugly (and probably less escure than a token)

Comment: Hey though... Look what I found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514062/cherrypy-rest-authentication

Comment: I saw that post before, but it's the same issue, can do it with Basic or Digest auth, but I want to have a REST Api with token auth, so my front end can have a login form and not a pop login and also be more secure with the ajax call not having any login data, you just need to give to the request headers your token

Comment: Have you seen this?: https://cherrypy.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.0/tutorial/REST.html 
just weeding out the small stuff...